# bash script to run a command and output errors or create a file

Tags: linux, bash

So i'm trying to write a bash script that runs a command and if it succeeds creates a file but if it fails it will create an error file with the output.

This is what i have so far....

```
#!/bin/bash
Command
if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "Command Failed" >& /home/admin/errorcheck
    exit 1
else
    echo " " > file1
fi
```

now i know it's currently failing but that's by design but it's not giving me any output at all or creating the file i need, any ideas would be great.

Comment: Does the `Command` run properly when used in command-line? Did you check its exit codes properly before using it in script?

Comment: Command runs but what it's trying to do fails mid way, the error is: ERROR: db was unsuccessful to dump at this time

Comment: why are you using Command? what is that line 2 for?,  it will complain Command: command not found.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer Pretty sure Command is a placeholder for the actual command...

Comment: You can use something like this if you pass an argument `Command="$?"` and evaluate that in your if condition.

Comment: Your script itself is mostly OK; the problem appears to be that your command doesn't actually exit with a non-zero status as a result of the database error.

Comment: Does "Command" output error messages to stderr?  If so then you might be able to redirect them then test the size of the output file.